# jQuery toggleClass persist over page refreshes?

Tags: html, jquery, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm using jQuery to change the background color of `td`'s in a table when the user clicks on that `td`. I want to do this to indicate which `td`'s were most recently updated (table is populated with MongoDB data and updated via HTML form). I'm using Nodejs/Express for the routes.

Is there a way to have this jQuery command persist over page refreshes and page loads? I don't want to use local storage because that's only specific to each user. I want it to persist so that when any user visits the site, they can see which cells were updated. I'm just not sure how to do this (or if it's even possible?) with the jQuery `toggleClass` feature.

jQuery function

```js
  $( function() {
    $('td').click( function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("color");
    } );
  } );
```

html table:

```html
<table>
   <% environments.forEach(function(environment){ %>

     <tr>
         <td><%= environment.ePIMS %></td>
         <td><%= environment.codeVersion %></td>
         <td><%= environment.region %></td>
     </tr>

   <% }); %> 
 </table>
```

**JSFiddle example of how the code above works:**

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mghbaLz6/)

Comment: *"with the jQuery toggleClass feature*" - put simply: no.  This is for updating the current page, it will not be persisted - it has less lifetime that local storage that you've already identified doesn't have enough scope.  You can send an ajax request to your server to store the information so that it's loaded for each user from a central location.

Comment: @freedomn-m huh okay that's kind of what i assumed...i'm not that familiar with ajax requests, do you think you could point me in the direction on where i could get started with that?

Comment: I think you don't need `onclick="function()"` for the table element.

Comment: @antlis haha you're right. that was leftover from when i was testing out different ways of changing the color. thanks for the catch!